# Youtube URL validation ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, youtube

I am using this method to validate youtube url but it's not working.

```
    -(BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate
{

    NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http://youtu.be/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)";


    urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];

    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];

}

-(BOOL) validateUrl1: (NSString *) candidate1
{


    NSString *urlRegEx1 = @"(https://(www|m){0,1}.youtube.com/(watch|playlist)[?]v=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)";


    urlTest1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx1];


    return [urlTest1 evaluateWithObject:candidate1];

}
```

> Even if I edit the url and make it y.be instead of youtu.be, still
>   these methods are returning YES

. Kindly tell me what's wrong in my code.
If any one has a better RegEx please share that with me.
I would also like to know how to write a RegEx.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if String is the link to the youtube video (not the link for channel, or for embedding video):

```
func isYoutubeLink(checkString checkString: String) -> Bool {

let youtubeRegex = "(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?(www\\.|m\\.)?youtu(be\\.com|\\.be)(\\/watch\\?([&=a-z]{0,})(v=[\\d\\w]{1,}).+|\\/[\\d\\w]{1,})"

let youtubeCheckResult = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", youtubeRegex)
return youtubeCheckResult.evaluateWithObject(checkString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL_STRING"];
    NSString *urlRegEx = @"(?:(?:\.be\/|embed\/|v\/|\\?v=|\&v=|\/videos\/)|(?:[\\w+]+#\\w\/\\w(?:\/[\\w]+)?\/\\w\/))([\\w-_]+)";
    NSPredicate *urlPredic = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    BOOL isValidURL = [urlPredic evaluateWithObject:urlString];

if(isValidURL)
{
  // your URL is valid;
}
else
{
  // show alert message for invalid URL;
}
```

now please check let me know i'm waiting your replay it's work or not.

Comment: i tried using this code but, even if i pass facebook url this function is returning true.

Comment: may i know your Youtube URL which your using

Comment: please use again this code i change this url:- 

    NSString *urlRegEx = @"(?:(?:\.be\/|embed\/|v\/|\\?v=|\&v=|\/videos\/)|(?:[\\w+]+#\\w\/\\w(?:\/[\\w]+)?\/\\w\/))([\\w-_]+)";

Answer (score 0):

If it is regex that you are looking for, then perhaps you could try this:

`(((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.|m\.)?(?:youtube\.[a-z]{2,}|youtu\.be)(?:\/(?:playlist|watch\?|channel\/|user\/)[\w=]+)+)`

It will match:

- `http://`, `https://` or none of these
- `www.` or `m.` or none of these
- `youtube.<anyTLD>` or `youtu.be`
- `/`
- `playlist`, `watch?`, `channel` or `user`
- a string of characters from `a-zA-Z0-9` and `=` more than 1 time

This should effectively match most urls on Youtube apart from the homepage, which if requested I could add in with a bit of tweaking.

You may have to add another escape, I haven't got much experience with objective-c

`(((?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.|m\.)?(?:youtube\\.[a-z]{2,}|youtu\\.be)(?:\\/(?:playlist|watch\\?|channel\\/|user\\/)[\\w=]+)+)`

Here is an example of it working in Javascript, Python and PCRE:

https://regex101.com/r/sG1xP7/1

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 5:**

```
func isValidYouTubeLink(givenString: String) -> Bool {
        
        let youtubeRegex = "(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?(www\\.|m\\.)?youtu(be\\.com|\\.be)(\\/watch\\?([&=a-z]{0,})(v=[\\d\\w]{1,}).+|\\/[\\d\\w]{1,})"
        let youtubeCheckResult = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", youtubeRegex)
        return youtubeCheckResult.evaluate(with: givenString)

    }
```

Comment: It passed all the XCTest on all sort of url, this should be the accepted answered!